# Clean URLs config page not loading

Tags: 7

admin/config/search/clean-urls just isn't loading. I don't mean it shows a white screen or anything like that - the browser just doesn't load it at all. The browser's loading gif spins and it says "waiting for ".

I've disabled every single module I can; the only ones left have the ticks greyed out and cannot be disabled.

PHP memory limit is 1024M and execution time 60s.

There is nothing in php_errors.log or in (once I re-enabled it) dblog.

Version 7.40, but don't know how many versions it's been like this for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried letting it run for the full 60 seconds and then see what error it spits out? Seems like there's some kind of infinite loop there. Also in php.ini enable all the developer mode setting for "error_reporting"

Comment: Error reporting is on, but it doesn't stop trying to load after 60s, it just keeps spinning